# Apache:Do i need to add a record to my zone file for subdomains?

Tags: apache, dns, subdomain, config, zone

I need to make a subdomain for my main domain.  Now when doing so do I need to add a record to my zone file for this?  And if so what type of record, an A record? cname, or what?

Answer (score 0):

A name in DNS does not get any content by itself, so if you want a new name to have an IP address associated with it, you have to put it there. If the point is to have a web server at the new name, you pretty much have to put an IP address there.

A name in DNS can have a variety of record types associated with it. `A` records hold IPv4 addresses. `AAAA` records hold IPv6 addresses. `CNAME` records tell whoever is looking "Don't look here, go look for whatever you were looking for over at that other name instead". So if they came looking for an `A` and found a `CNAME`, they'll go look for an `A` somewhere else and return whatever they found over there.

So, if you want there to be an IPv4 address for your new name, put in an `A` record for it. If you want to say "This new name should be absolutely identical to that other name in every respect", put in a `CNAME` record for it.

If you aren't sure exactly what `CNAME` records mean, please don't use them.

Comment: well actually a CNAME record just points the a domain name, thats it.  It's just an alias to a domain name.  Reason why they use CNAME's for subdomains in general is because we want to connect to the main domain, and once connected let the default/local server of the domain decide where to route the subdomain request via virtualhost for instance...

Comment: I was just trying to explain how your "just an alias" actually works, since problems due to web developers not understanding precisely that are extremely common here on Stack Overflow. But never mind. Feel free to ignore.